# I think my phone might be infected

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, samsung-galaxy-s-6, spam

Over the last couple days, my phone has been acting weird. I have the Galaxy S6 Active. Over the last couple days, whenever I try to open something, rather than opening the app I want, it'll go directly to Uber in my play store. I haven't had any problems before. My phone did an update about 1 1/2 weeks ago and I didn't have problems then. I looked in my device manager to see if anything looks out of the norm or if anything downloaded that shouldn't and that's not the case. Is there anything that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If it's opening uber app directly in the app store, it must be an adware(malware that displays ads without your permission). Similar to the Google ads you see in different apps. These ads have to be called by an app. Think of it like their host. You can refference more from [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/android-app-displaying-popup-adverts/) 
So probabilities are:

1. Your running a custom OS which was altered to have these hidden behaviours.
2. There's a *funny* app installed on your phone that starts when your phone starts. It's trained to listen in when apps are called to open and sends you to Playstore instead.

To get rid of this you could,

1. If you have a custom OS confirm the authenticity of the build.
2. Still with a custom OS as superuser prevent any unofficial app from starring when the phone starts. If the behaviour is still persistent repeat the procedure until you find the app causing you this fault.
3. Go through your phone for any apps that aren't default and uninstall each of the apps while restarting your phone to ensure that all its files are deleted.
4. Simplest of these all: download ***[adware](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keerby.adaware&hl=en)*** from the google playstore.
5. If all these fails, then you might have no other option other than to factory reset your phone to its original state.

Also be very careful when installing apps. If you find something you don't know don't install it. I normally check through comments before installing any unpopular apps to avoid nasty surprises.